# Set constraints in custom Symfony FormType

Tags: symfony

Usually, to define constraints in the forms, we do this :

```
$builder->add('myfield', TextType::class, [
    'constraints' => [
        ...
    ]
])
```

But how to define constraints on a custom field ? **Without "add"** ?

```
class FineUploaderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void {
        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer($this->fineUploaderTransformer)
        ;

        // I want add constraints here
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return HiddenType::class;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's stated in the Symfony documentation [best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#validation) 
constraints should be defined on the object that form is mapped to. Maybe this will solve your problem? If you could give a wider context it could be easier to help :)

Comment: Yes, it's true :)

But I want to pass information from the parents form, example from parent form : `$builder->add('myfield', FineUploaderType::class, ['fine_uploader_validation' => 'custom_infos'])`

And send `custom_infos` to my constraints in `FineUploaderType`

Comment: Maybe Form Events and Event Listener could help OR if `getParent()` method returns your `FineUploaderType::class` try to add `parent::buildForm($builder, $options)` at the top of your `buildForm()` method and use `$builder->get('myField')` and extract the information you want from the field of parent FormType.